# how to get categories of posts within Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have Custom Post Type called "football_teams" which has 20 posts.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'              =>  'football_teams',
    'posts_per_page'         =>  '-1'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

how do I get categories of all those posts within the CPT.

I've tried `$cats = get_categories();` but it shows all the categories of all posts.

I've also tried `$cats = get_categories($args);` but didnt work.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to web-development.

Comment: You need to use a taxonomy query in your `$args` array. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Actually, a taxonomy query will query posts from certain taxonomies (categories). Are you trying to do that, or just get the categories of that post type to display the names or something else?

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies, get_object_taxonomies() accepts a post-type name as parameter.

Comment: The 20 posts that I have within the CPT (football_teams). I want the 'category names' of those 20 posts.

Comment: @Mtxz using $taxi = get_object_taxonomies('football_teams'); I'm only getting a string 'category' and not actually the names of the category.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use the [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function to get the term(category) name.
You can use the code below.
Note: the `$taxonomy` is your custom taxonomy. If you are not using custom taxonomy then it would be `category`.

```
<?php

$post_type = 'your post type';
$taxonomy = 'your taxonomy';

$args = [
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
];

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
        $categories = [];

        if( $terms ) {          
            foreach ($terms as $category) {
                $categories[] = $category->name;
            }       
        }

        $categories = implode(', ', $categories);

        echo get_the_title() .'| '. $categories .' <br>';
    }
}


Sample output:
my post 1 | category1, category2, category3
my post 2 | category2, category4, category5
```

Comment: I like the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

I can't like the answer as i don't have enough reputation. but i ticked it as the right answer

Comment: @johnsmith. Glad it helps. Cheers!